# Change button color of wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

Can you help me to find css of "Submit Listenig" button?
I want to change primary color.

http://demo.sabaiapps.com/sabaidirectory/businesses/add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sabai-btn {
display: inline-block !important;
padding: 4px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
color: #333333;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
background-color: #f5f5f5;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

Comment: Tnank you!! background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#c8d6ff,#c8d6ff);

Comment: You are Welcome friend.!

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-toggle, input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], article.post-password-required input[type=submit], li.bypostauthor cite span
```

style.css - Line 238

The button uses CSS gradients for background color.

http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="submit"].sabai-btn { background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#c8d6ff,#c8d6ff); }
```

This code changes only submit button. But hover effect changes. It hover only on half button.